# Difference between asp-fallback-test-property vs asp-fallback-test

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I am trying to figure out the difference between asp-fallback-test-property and asp-fallback-test, both use the property to figure out whether to fallback or not. Are they same or there is a difference

below link does not answer the difference and it is confusing.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1580

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51363291/107625)?

Comment: no, it does not talk about asp-fallback-test-property, it just touches it, am not sure i understand from the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`asp-fallback-test-property`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/LinkTagHelper.cs#L50) is specific to the `link` tag-helper. It's the name of a CSS property you want to be interrogated, with `asp-fallback-test-value` being the value you expect it to have (see the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51364959/2630078) I wrote for the specifics).

[`asp-fallback-test`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/ScriptTagHelper.cs#L42) is specific to the `script` tag-helper. It's just a JavaScript expression that will be evaluated - if it's truthy, no fallback will be used.

As an example of `asp-fallback-test`, imagine the following `script` tag:

```
<script src="/some/cdn/to/jquery"
    asp-fallback-src="~/local/path/to/jquery"
    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"></script>
```

In this example, after the browser attempts to load the script from `/some/cdn/to/jquery`, the tag-helper will check whether `window.jQuery` is truthy. If it is, there's nothing more to do. If it isn't (the CDN script couldn't be downloaded), it will inject a `script` tag for `~/local/path/to/jquery`.

Comment: Hi @kirk-larkin Can you please explain how window.jQuery becomes truthy in this example? Does that mean the script file has to have window.jquery present somewhere on the file?

Comment: @ConsoleLog Yes, that's right. Open this site in the developer tools of your browser, open the console and type `!!window.jQuery`. You'll see that's `true`. The jQuery script adds that `jQuery` property onto `window`. If the script doesn't load, it doesn't set the property, so `!!window.jQuery` will show `false`.

Comment: Thereby, if we implement fallbacks for multiple files we have to find unique 'methods' for each script, am I correct in thinking that way? Cheers!

Comment: @ConsoleLog Yes, for jQuery it's `window.jQuery`, but for e.g. [lodash](https://lodash.com/) it would be `window._`. Each library adds its own "thing" to `window` - the `asp-fallback-test` is different for each one of these.