# ASP.NET Core asp-fallback tag helper with pseudo selectors (and bootstrap-icons)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6, with the `asp-fallback` feature of the `<link>` tag helper (I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51363291/9971404) how to use it, and it works well for me).

I'm also using the Bootstrap Icons [library](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/). I can't get it to work with fallbacks because it uses pseudo selectors only ([example](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css)).

Is there a way to use the fallback mechanism with pseudo selectors? If not, is there some workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LinkTagHelper` fallback mechanism does not support pseudo selectors. There is a tracking issue on [the repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38146), so maybe it'll be fixed in v7.

Until then I'm using a **WORKAROUND**. I extended the framework's [fallback code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0b1e29fc4d0b8a4f50ecf36832fa6a4e4ea94a3c/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/LinkTagHelper.cs) to also consider pseudo selectors.

Add this to the DOM:

```
@{
  var testClass          = "bi";
  var testPseudoSelector = "::before";
  var testProperty       = "font-family";
  var testValue          = "bootstrap-icons !important";
  var hrefFallback       = "/bootstrap-icons.css";
}
<meta name="x-stylesheet-fallback-test" content="" class="@testClass" />
<script>
  var scriptTag  = document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT');                      // this tag is "last" when browser gets here
  var metaTag    = scriptTag[scriptTag.length - 1].previousElementSibling;       // ...so meta tag immediately before is the one we want
  var metaStyles = document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle
    ? document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(metaTag, '@testPseudoSelector')      // here is the magic
    : metaTag.currentStyle;
  if (metaStyles && metaStyles['@testProperty'] !== '@testValue')
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + '@hrefFallback' + '" crossorigin="anonymous" />');
</script>
```

That is very similar to what the tag helper does, except it also considers the `::before` pseudo selector using the `getComputedStyle(element, pseudoSelector)` [override](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

I only need this workaround for one library (bootstrap-icons), but if you find you use it repeatedly, you could refactor it into a custom tag helper, e.g. `PseudoSelectorAwareLinkTagHelper`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've just tried it and using the above property of font-family then  metaStyles['@testProperty'] = 'bootstrap-icons', even though the CSS file shows 'bootstrap-icons !important'. I've changed to the following

  var testValue = "bootstrap-icons";

Also, the semi-colon needs removing at the end of the if statement

Comment: @Dave Glad it helped. It's been a while since I've looked at this code, there were probably changes in the latest version, and you're more familiar with it - so if you'd like, feel free to edit the answer.